# How to format numbers with locale based decimal separator in Perl?

Tags: perl, locale

I seek for way to use locale-based decimal separator in my perl-scripts. For now i don't see  better solution than just `s/\./,/` in specific places, but it is ugly and i'd like to have more clean solution.

Comment: Perl module Number::Format is locale aware, and does a pretty good job formatting numbers using the locale information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [perllocale manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#Category-LC_NUMERIC%3a-Numeric-Formatting) might be useful.  It also has examples.

Comment: Thank you! It was while ago but i seeked it there... Anyway, it works!